# How to install unofficial Firebase extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looking for information on steps to install the unofficial firestore-nlp-extension, link below.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firestore-nlp-extension

I read the [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/install-extensions?platform=cli#install) but did not see instructions to install a "custom" extension.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the extension from a local source but this was available during the alpha and the below link is no longer working

https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/alpha/install-extensions_community#install

The specific extension does not seem to be available on the Firebase system:

> Error: The extension reference
> 'firebase/firestore-natural-language-processing@latest' doesn't exist.
> This could happen for two reasons:   -The publisher ID 'firebase'
> doesn't exist or could be misspelled   -The name of the extension
> version 'firestore-natural-language-processing@latest' doesn't exist
> or could be misspelled

For the current beta from the cli tool I found the following:

First, clone the git repo of the extension:

```
git clone git@github.com:FirebaseExtended/firestore-nlp-extension.git
```

then run the following commands to build the project:

```
cd firestore-nlp-extension/functions
yarn add -D rimraf
yarn build
cd ../..
```

and then to install this extension, run:

```
firebase ext:install ./firestore-nlp-extension --project=YOUR_PROJECT
```

if you get a path error you might need to find the right path such as:

```
firebase ext:install ./firestore-nlp-extension/functions --project=YOUR_PROJECT
```

Comment: Thanks this is getting me close. During install I'm getting an error: ""Build failed: lib/index.js does not exist". Anyone experience this error?

Comment: You need to build the library. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, no idea why I didn't think this package needed to be built. Just installed, no issues. Much appreciated!